# Using a presentation pointer with Android tablet

Tags: bluetooth, tablet, usb-on-the-go, nvidia-shield, video-out

I have recently bought the Nvidia Shield Tablet, which happens to have Mini HDMI output. As a PhD student in Maths (potentially staying in academia afterwards), I give and will most likely continue to give presentations on a regular basis and was wondering whether it would be possible to do away with bringing my heavy laptop to conferences and just completely rely on my tablet instead.

It seems like the answer is positive, as there are Android versions of pretty much all the computing software I use and a Bluetooth keyboard should allow for a rather smooth 'working experience'. One final issue that stands out is presentations and in particular the comfort of having a pointer to work with. The way cheap wireless pointers work these days is that you simply plug in a small usb stick to your laptop and immediately it starts to work. Can something similar be achieved with Android? Quickness is key here, I really want to be able to just plug things in and be good to go. I can see two possibilities:

1) Use the so-called USB On-The-Go adapter (micro USB to normal USB) and then plug in the usb stick provided. Any chance of this simple approach being a solution?
2) Buy a more sophisticated pointer which has Bluetooth support and use it to connect it to your device. I guess once it is connected it should work immediately?

King apologies if this question is a duplicate (I sincerely think it isn't, I have done a fair bit of digging) or whether the answer is simply 'both (1) and (2) will work', but I just wanted to be sure before I order relevant accessories.

Comment: May I offer a third option?  Buy a ~$30 (USD) Chromecast device and _mirror_ your tablet to a display - using no connecting wires.  Then you can hold your tablet and use your fingers to manipulate your presentations.  A Chromecast is generally smaller than a mouse, too.  This is my go to method for presenting.

Comment: This is an interesting idea I haven't thought about. One potential 'deal-breaker' though is that Chromecast appears to require an internet connection, which needs to be set up after connecting to a display- is that correct? Even worse, isn't it true that both the tablet and the chromecast need to be connected to the same wifi? This is somewhat disastrous if I use any sort of 'corporate' wifi, isn't it?

Comment: Doesn't necessarily have to be Chromecast - there are lots of Miracast-based solutions (some bearing the shape of a Chromecast, essentially a knockoff), some would create its own local WiFi network for you to connect to and mirror the screen within.

Comment: Many thanks, I'll consider it, but probably only if the first option I mention in my question is proven to be not satisfactory. If it is okay though, it looks like the cheapest and most hassle-free way to go about it.